# RoboGuice and ActionbarSherlock seems to not work together

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, roboguice

Here is the thing:

I'm using roboguice-sherlock to work both ActionBarSherlock and RoboGuice, and want to use the `@ContentView()` feature of RoboGuice to inject the layout, also want to `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)` in `onCreate()` to show Indeterminate progress bar.

After this, a runtime exception was caught:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Is this a bug or I just doing wrong?

For example, in sample-roboguice of actionbarsherlock samples, if  `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)` is added in the `onCreate()` method just below `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`, the sample crashes at runtime with the exceptions above.

Comment: Can you add more code so we can get it clearly..!! :)

Comment: Just add one line, the sample code will crash at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Just call requestWindowFeature() before super.onCreate(). It should fix your problem.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // do some epic things
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the trick by now. But not for sure whether this is the final solution.

Comment: In fact, the requestWindowFeature() should be called before any views are rendered